# after adding bridge, services on host are no longer reacheable from other hosts

Tags: networking, server, services, network-bridge

Before adding the bridge, different http services were reachable from other hosts.

After adding the bridge, only ssh is reachable from other hosts.
All other services are only reachable from the host itself, over localhost or the IP of the bridge adapter.

On the host, NO firewall is active, other hosts can ping the host and connect via ssh and scp, but the different web services are not rechargeable from other machines.
other services are http based, on non interfering ports:
9090, 8001, 7070

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enp0s25
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

iface enp0s25 inet manual
```

output of: ifconfig

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.203.114.247  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.203.255.255
    inet6 fe80::221:ccff:fe4b:313a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:21:cc:4b:31:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 23803  bytes 23963479 (23.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7365  bytes 806013 (806.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:02:a9:df:4e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:21:cc:4b:31:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 559347  bytes 511837384 (511.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 325  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 94679  bytes 8350357 (8.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xd2600000-d2620000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2722645  bytes 766563500 (766.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2722645  bytes 766563500 (766.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:db:37:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 323  bytes 45009 (45.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 170  bytes 13961 (13.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The bridge is now using the same DCHP config as the enp0s25 before and also has the same IP. This worked on other hosts without issues.
Outside machines and their services can be reached from the host OS or VMs without issues. Inbound, ONLY ssh is reacheable, even if services are configured to run on 0.0.0.0.

Any ideas, whats blocking the other services ?

Comment: try eliminating the redundant entries in your interfaces file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but those were only redundant in the forum post.